# Angular promise won't catch exceptions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, exception, promise

I have a login function and I want to catch the exceptions launched by the server and bubble them up to the view with an error message. So far I used `promise` to handle the asyncronous part, and I want to use the `catch()` part to catch my exception. The problem is that the `handler` function never gets called and I get the error in the browser console. This is my code so far, very basic:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Promise<User> {

    return this.http
      .get(this.loginUrl + '?username=' + username + '&password=' + password)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(function(e){
          this.handler(e);
      })
  }

  handler (e: Response){
    throw e;
  }
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks.

**Edit**
I used `arrow function` as suggested, now my code looks like this:

*user.service.ts*

```
login(username: string, password: string): Promise<User> {

    return this.http
      .get(this.loginUrl + '?username=' + username + '&password=' + password)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(e => {
          this.handler;
      })
  }

  handler (e: Response){
    throw e;

  }
```

*login.component.ts*

```
onSubmit(loginForm: NgForm): string {

    this.userService.login(loginForm.value.username, loginForm.value.password)
    .then(data => {

      this.message = 'Nome: ' + data.nome +
                    ' Cognome: ' +data.cognome + 
                    ' Azienda: ' + data.azienda +
                    ' Ufficio: ' + data.ufficio;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        this.message = e;
      });

    return this.message;
  }
```

Still, I get my exception from server but the application skips the `catch()` blocks.

Comment: what is the exception in a console?

Comment: You are throwing the exception in the handler again? Also if you wish to use `this` you should use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of an anonymous function

Comment: @Maximus is a `401 Unauthorized`, but I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @0mpurdy I was, but the arrow function was the key point. I will edit my code for further references with the solution. If you put your comment as answer I'll choose it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: @0mpurdy I was wrong, see my edit.

Comment: @esseara Looks like there already is an answer to that effect, it's fine to accept that :) Also, I'm not sure, but it would probably be best not to include the answer in your question - it may confuse future visitors :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you should use arrow functions, and that is not how you handle `async` requests. At first you should indeed not use the `function` keyword, but the arrow notation. But in your catch statement you don't initiate the `handler` function.

On the other hand you are trying to return a string in the `onSubmit`. But the method obtaining this string is `async`. You can leverage the `TypeScript` `await` and `async` functionality for this.

**user.service.ts**

```
login(username: string, password: string): Promise<User> {

    return this.http
      .get(this.loginUrl + '?username=' + username + '&password=' + password)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handler)
}

handler = (e: Response) => {
    throw e;
};
```

Notice the arrow function assignment.

**login.component.ts**

```
async onSubmit(loginForm: NgForm): Promise<string> {

    try {
       const data: any = await this.userService.login(loginForm.value.username, loginForm.value.password);
       this.message = `Nome: ${data.nome} Cognome: ${data.cognome} Azienda: ${data.azienda} Ufficio: ${data.ufficio}`;
    } catch (e) {
       this.message = e;
    }    

    return this.message;
}
```

Notice that your `onSubmit` now returns a `Promise<string>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Could you explain why my solution for async call isn't correct?

Comment: When it reaches `return this.message`, this has not been set yet, because the `this.userService.login` method is async. Which means it will reach the `.then` when the method has already returned